# Building and installing C* Music Player (CMUS)

Tags: fedora, software-installation, compiling

I really like `C* Music Player` (CMUS) and I just installed Fedora 22 because I had issues with Fedora 21. The thing is that I cannot find any executable to install this music player. 
I tried with `dnf` and didn't work, here's the output:

```
Last metadata expiration check performed 1:10:46 ago on Sun Jul 26 16:14:36 2015.
No package cmus available.
Error: no package matched: cmus
```

I find this answer on FedoraProject.Org: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/68940/where-can-i-find-cmus-program-for-fedora/

It says that if you have rpmfusion installed the use of `dnf` will be enough. I installed rpmfusion and tried again without any success. Here's how I installed rpmfusion free and non-free:

```
wget http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-22.noarch.rpm
dnf install rpmfusion-free-release-22.noarch.rpm

wget http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-22.noarch.rpm
dnf install rpmfusion-nonfree-release-22.noarch.rpm
```

After that, I decided to compile the source code myself and tried that, I installed `gcc` and tried:
`./configure` and here's the output of that:

```
checking for program gcc... /usr/bin/gcc
checking for program gcc... /usr/bin/gcc
checking for CFLAGS -std=gnu99 -pipe -Wall -Wshadow -Wcast-align -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wformat-security... yes
checking for CFLAGS -Wold-style-definition... yes
checking for CFLAGS -Wno-pointer-sign... yes
checking for CFLAGS -Werror-implicit-function-declaration... yes
checking for CFLAGS -Wno-unused-parameter... yes
checking if CC can generate dependency information... yes
checking byte order... little-endian
checking for DL_LIBS (-ldl -Wl,--export-dynamic)... yes
checking for PTHREAD_LIBS (-lpthread)... yes
checking for realtime scheduling... yes
checking for program pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for NCURSES_LIBS (pkg-config)... no
checking for NCURSES_LIBS (-lncursesw)... no
checking for NCURSES_LIBS (pkg-config)... no
checking for NCURSES_LIBS (-lncurses)... no
checking for NCURSES_LIBS (pkg-config)... no
checking for NCURSES_LIBS (-lcurses)... no
configure failed.
```

And I have no idea what I'm missing to install `C* Music Player` (CMUS) and I would like your help,.

Maybe I didn't install rmpfusion free-repositories/non-free-repositories the way it should be or I'm not installing everything I need to install before compiling the source code (I have no idea what `NCURSES_LIBS` is.) I'll go with any solution you can provide for this,. Thank you in advance.

PS. I actually installed `ncurses ncurses-devel`. And proceed with `./configure`. Here's the output:

```
checking for program gcc... /usr/bin/gcc
checking for program gcc... /usr/bin/gcc
checking for CFLAGS -std=gnu99 -pipe -Wall -Wshadow -Wcast-align -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wformat-security... yes
checking for CFLAGS -Wold-style-definition... yes
checking for CFLAGS -Wno-pointer-sign... yes
checking for CFLAGS -Werror-implicit-function-declaration... yes
checking for CFLAGS -Wno-unused-parameter... yes
checking if CC can generate dependency information... yes
checking byte order... little-endian
checking for DL_LIBS (-ldl -Wl,--export-dynamic)... yes
checking for PTHREAD_LIBS (-lpthread)... yes
checking for realtime scheduling... yes
checking for program pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for NCURSES_LIBS (pkg-config)... -lncursesw 
checking for NCURSES_CFLAGS (pkg-config)... 
checking for working ncurses setup... yes
checking for function resizeterm... yes
checking for function use_default_colors... yes
checking for ICONV_LIBS (-liconv)... no
assuming libc contains iconv
checking for working iconv... yes
checking for header <byteswap.h>... yes
checking for function strdup... yes
checking for function strndup... yes
checking for CDDB_LIBS (pkg-config)... no
checking for CDDB_LIBS (-lcddb)... no
checking for CDIO_LIBS (pkg-config)... no
checking for CDIO_LIBS (-lcdio_cdio -lcdio -lm)... no
checking for FLAC_LIBS (pkg-config)... no
checking for FLAC_LIBS (-lFLAC -lm)... no
checking for MAD_LIBS (pkg-config)... no
checking for MAD_LIBS (-lmad -lm)... no
checking for MODPLUG_LIBS (pkg-config)... no
checking for MODPLUG_LIBS (-lmodplug -lstdc++ -lm)... no
checking for header <mpc/mpcdec.h>... no
checking for header <mpcdec/mpcdec.h>... no
checking for VORBIS_LIBS (pkg-config)... no
checking for VORBIS_LIBS (-lvorbisfile -lvorbis -lm -logg)... no
checking for OPUS_LIBS (pkg-config)... no
*** Package opusfile was not found in the pkg-config search path.
*** Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opusfile.pc'
*** to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
*** No package 'opusfile' found
checking for WAVPACK_LIBS (pkg-config)... no
checking for WAVPACK_LIBS (-lwavpack)... no
checking for header <mp4v2/mp4v2.h>... no
checking for header <mp4.h>... no
checking for header <neaacdec.h>... no
checking for FFMPEG_LIBS (pkg-config)... no
*** Package libavformat was not found in the pkg-config search path.
*** Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libavformat.pc'
*** to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
*** No package 'libavformat' found
checking for CUE_LIBS (pkg-config)... no
*** Package libcue was not found in the pkg-config search path.
*** Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcue.pc'
*** to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
*** No package 'libcue' found
checking for header <ayemu.h>... no
checking for PULSE_LIBS (pkg-config)... no
*** Package libpulse was not found in the pkg-config search path.
*** Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libpulse.pc'
*** to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
*** No package 'libpulse' found
checking for ALSA_LIBS (pkg-config)... no
*** Package alsa was not found in the pkg-config search path.
*** Perhaps you should add the directory containing `alsa.pc'
*** to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
*** No package 'alsa' found
checking for JACK_LIBS (pkg-config)... no
*** Package jack was not found in the pkg-config search path.
*** Perhaps you should add the directory containing `jack.pc'
*** to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
*** No package 'jack' found
checking for SAMPLERATE_LIBS (pkg-config)... no
*** Package samplerate was not found in the pkg-config search path.
*** Perhaps you should add the directory containing `samplerate.pc'
*** to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
*** No package 'samplerate' found
checking for AO_LIBS (pkg-config)... no
checking for AO_LIBS (-lao)... no
checking for program artsc-config... no
checking for header <sys/soundcard.h>... yes
checking for header <sys/audioio.h>... no
checking for ROAR_LIBS (pkg-config)... no
*** Package libroar was not found in the pkg-config search path.
*** Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libroar.pc'
*** to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
*** No package 'libroar' found
creating config/cdio.h
creating config/datadir.h
creating config/libdir.h
creating config/debug.h
creating config/tremor.h
creating config/modplug.h
creating config/mpc.h
creating config/mp4.h
creating config/curses.h
creating config/ffmpeg.h
creating config/utils.h
creating config/iconv.h
creating config/samplerate.h
creating config/xmalloc.h
creating config/cue.h
creating config.mk
```

And after that I use `make` and `make install`. It actually installed `C* Music player*`but it gives me an error: `Error: selecting output plugin '': no such plugin.` Sigh. Any other thoughts about this?

Comment: I've edited my answer too. Try: `sudo yum install ffmpeg-libs ffmpeg-devel libcue libcue-devel pulseaudio-libs pulseaudio-libs-devel libsamplerate-devel libsamplerate` and re-run your ./configure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a library called **ncurses** which is used by your application. Just install it with `sudo yum install ncurses ncurses-devel`

As your are building it from sources, you'll need to satisfy the dependencies yourself. That's what rpm packages are meant for : listing dependencies, resolving and installing them so the requested package will work.

Edit: According to your output, you're now missing some libraries to send sound to your soundcard. Try :
`sudo yum install ffmpeg-libs ffmpeg-devel libcue libcue-devel pulseaudio-libs pulseaudio-libs-devel libsamplerate-devel libsamplerate`

It may install multiple dependancies, but it should match your configuration. Once installed, re-run the "./configure".

Comment: do you think that might be everything I need to successfully install `cmus`?

Comment: Now's better but the error still there. But now it allows me to add the music but when I try to play the songs tell me same error, 'Error: selecting output plugin : no such plugin'. Sigh, And I cannot find any RPM with this version of CMUS.

Comment: *** Package alsa was not found in the pkg-config search path.
*** Perhaps you should add the directory containing "alsa.pc"
*** to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
*** No package "alsa" found,.
It tells me similar three times with `alsa.pc`, `jack.pc`, `libroar.pc`.

Comment: It's now working, I searched for the error and did this: `:set
output_plugin=pulse` and it's playing well now. Thank you so much.